# Sleep Hours during Heavy Hard work

Tags: health, sleep

Assume , you are preparing for the world's toughest Examination, where a lot of Hard work is required to crack the Exam.

How many hours of sleep would be enough to maximize your study hours but also maintaining good mental and physical health?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the second paragraph. Is this question about physical activity?

Comment: of-course not..that only meant under-sleeping can also have adverse effect on physical health as well.you can't give your 100% if you are physically sick.

Comment: Your question is off topic then, questions should be about physical fitness, but not about general health advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually sleeping 8 hours are good for health, but at least 6 hours are compulsory, otherwise you will feel tired after few days and may effect your studies. so sleep at least 6 hours